# Gerrit JS Plugin - Alter Reply Popup

Tags: javascript, gerrit

Gerrit creates and injects to the DOM a popup when a user clicks the "Reply" button:

[image]

As this element is not in the DOM when the change screen is loaded, the contents can not be modified in the Gerrit.on('showchange', myHandler); hook.

How would you register additional event handlers in order to modify the popup content?